# How to call a private method on library codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a library called privacy, I made a function private called _user_block_by_team
and i want call this function on another public function on the same library like the following code, but it give to me an error `Fatal error: Call to undefined method Team::_user_block_by_team()` where i'm doing mistake? This library is on autoload from the file autoload.php

```
class Privacy {

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->ci =& get_instance();    
    }

    function user_block_team($id_user) {
        $this->ci->_user_block_by_team($id_user);
    }

    function _user_block_by_team($id_user) {
        $this->ci->load->library('settings');
        if ($this->ci->settings->check_user_blocked($id_user)) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: No need to use $this->ci, just use $this->

Answer (score 7):

You can just call `$this->_user_block_by_team($id_user)`.